# Extracting Organization and EC2 informations using javascript aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-organizations

I am using express to make a light application that will display information about an organizations accounts and eventually EC2 instances. As of now I just want to save Account Id's into an array and print that array on a page. My code is:

```
//  service/myjavascript.js
function orgs(req, res) {
    var accts = ['3442578432'];
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'MY_KEY', secretAccessKey: 'MY_SECRET', region: 'MY_REGION'});
    console.log("1111");
    var params = {
              MaxResults: 3
            };
    var organizations = new AWS.Organizations(params);
    organizations.listAccounts(function (err, data) {
          if (err) 
              console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     
              for(var i = 0; i < data['Accounts'].length; i++) { 
                  accts.push(data['Accounts'][i]['Id']);
              }
              console.log("2222:);// successful response
              console.log(accts);

        });
console.log("3333");
return accts;
}
```

I then call my page and this is what shows up in my console

```
1111
3333
GET /testpage 304 21.637 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 21.637 ms - -
2222
["3442578432","3001378432,"5742579932","9742654332"]
```

My page will then display "3442578432" 
but I want it to display ["3442578432","3001378432,"5742579932","9742654332"]

I am very confused on why I ordered the execution of code incorrectly, as well as why I can not save the information from this api call into an array. In the future I will need to make more calls to more services and I can't even store and display the account numbers on a page.

I am also confused on why if I do:

```
var orgData  = organizations.listAccounts(...
```

I get a big chunk of meta data that doesn't contain any of my account info.

Comment: there is an error when it recovers the `listAccounts`. it is not pushing new values to the `accts` variable. Can you test if there are not errors??

Comment: I'm not super adept at JavaScript, but it looks to me, based on your logging, that you're returning `acct` prior to the contents of `listAccounts` actually executing. Maybe due to an [async](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_async.html) framework somewhere else in your project?

Comment: @KenrySanchez When I run this function as is I get no errors. The 'accts' are populated just not when I want them to be. When the function executes organizations.listAccounts(... ) doesn't run until after the page has been loaded hence why we get a 304, and THEN the 'accts' variable is populated in the 'console.log(accts)'. My 'accts' variable is recognized and returned, just before 'listAccounts' has a chance to run.

Comment: @MrDuk It does seems to be being executed out of order. However I don't have anything else in my project, this is basically it. I thought a function would execute each line of code top to bottom, one after another but it seems to be executing everything else first including the return statement before it runs the 'listAccounts', which is run after the page is loaded.

Comment: This functon *does* run exactly from top to bottom.  The `organizations.listAccounts()` call is asynchronous, so when execution reaches that line, the request **is started**.  Async methods don't block while waiting for a response -- they fire their callback function when they finish or fail.